# Are there any non-mesh packing cubes, if not what can I use?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage

I love mesh packing cubes for my large suitcase which I check on flights.  For my backpack however, I want to put my emergency change of clothes in something liquid-resistant, since I often also pack food and beverages in there. Know of any brands out there, or another equivalent solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Eagle Creek Specter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005SKJ53K) cube series seems to be just what I am looking for.  Still a packing cube design for easy access, but non-mesh for liquid protection. On top of that, it is translucent to allow cursory inventorying, and is supposed to be especially light. I'll let you all know how my purchase fares.

Comment: I assumed the worst case with a broken bottle inside and a rugged ride... :).

Comment: Just an update here. The Specter is a great lightweight packing cube, and is not mesh so solid dirt would stay separated. But it would provide almost no protection against liquids.  For that I now use the Eagle Creek Pack-It Clean/Dirty Split Cube which has a water resistant section.

Answer (score 3):

What you seem to need are waterresistant rolling bags like [that](http://www.ortlieb.de/_prod.php?lang=en&produkt=drybag_ps10). *Ortlieb* is a well-known brand name, but also a bit expensive. If you look out in outdoor stores or motorbike stores (they have often inexpensive bags which are used to store things which should not get wet), you should be able to get an inexpensive brand.

Comment: I had never heard of these, interesting option +1.  Because they are more geared for heavy-duty liquid protection, I think my particular needs are better served by a traditional packing cube due to the ease of packing and unpacking clothes. I've since found a cube that fits the bill (see answer).